# Wiring beans into TestNG listener that implements IInvokedMethodListener

Tags: spring, testng, spring-3

I have a TestNG listener that implements `IInvokedMethodListener`. I would like to wire in a Spring bean inside this listener and use it. Unfortunately, this class is instantiated by TestNG and so Spring cannot wire anything in that is annotated using `@Autowired`. I tried implementing `ApplicationContextAware`, but that doesn't work either.

Is there a way to wire Spring beans into classes that implement `IInvokedMethodListener`?

Answer (score 2):

`ApplicationContextAware` only works for Spring Beans. You can use [@Configurable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#aop-atconfigurable), but that requires AspectJ.

Here's a simple hack that should work: Add a static member to your listener class and inject it via a non-static setter.

```
public class MyMethodListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

   private static MyBean myBean;

   @Autowired
   public void setMyBean(MyBean myBean) {
        MyMethodListener.myBean = myBean;
   }
}
```

Include a bean of the required type in your application context.

The listener instantiated by TestNG will not be the same instance as the one from the Spring context, but it will have the static member set, provided that context creation has finished before TestNG instantiates the listener.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently, it is basically Listeners are not maintained by spring. So I did some googling around this concept like "Injecting beans into classes not managed by spring", I got https://dzone.com/articles/autowiring-spring-beans-into-classes-not-managed-by-spring link which explains exactly the same problem and the solution. It worked for me.

Comment: but Listeners are created before spring context is initialized no? When i try this the BeanUtil bean isnt initialized (e.g the context is null )